# How can I fix an iPhone 2G that is stuck on the connect to iTunes screen?

Tags: itunes, iphone, jailbreak

I have an old iPhone 2G (first generation) that I plan on using basically as an iPod touch (not using the phone portion).  I no longer have the AT&T service on that phone.  I installed an update to the firmware (stupidly) this morning because iTunes prompted me too... and now the phone seems to basically be bricked.  Upon completing the firmware update I was stuck at the "connect to iTunes/emergency" screen.

For the past 10 hours, I have tried to restore, I have booted into DFU mode. I have even resorted to attempted jailbreaks, all to no avail.  No matter what I do, I still get that "connect to iTunes/emergency" screen, and while the "iPhone" displays under Devices in iTunes, the iTunes page simply says "iPhone". There is no Summary Page, no iPhone section, no version section, no backup section, etc.

I installed iTunes 10.5 and I am pretty sure the firmware for the 2G phone is 1.1.3 (although I had attempted to roll it back).

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and what can be done to get this iPhone back up and running?

Comment: You need to "activate" your phone. Try this guide: http://www.ilikemyiphone.com/2010/02/10/jailbreak-activate-and-unlock-original-iphone-2g-3-1-3-firmware-using-redsn0w-windowsmac/

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreaking is the easiest way to kill the activation process, fortunately for you the 2G is cracked on such a low level is a one shot process [there's a guide up on iClarified how to do it](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=7430).

After that you should go have a look at [which is a jailbroken firmware](http://www.whited00r.com/) with a lot of the features that the iPhone 2G ended up missing out on.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is restored and updated to new firmware, to activate the phone you need to have AT&T service.

Plan B: Jailbreak it with Cydia. It will unlock your phone and you can use it with other service providers. There are many videos on youtube to guide you.

Comment: Unlocking your phone requires Utrasnow. Cydia is just an alternative installer and has nothing to do with it. Moreover unlocking a phone is a completely separate process to that of jail breaking.

Comment: Cydia doesn't work on iPhones below the 3GS.

Comment: Is that a recent change? I used it with my iPhone 3G years ago.